Invalid certificate for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/
Invalid certificate for https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/
Does anyone have a similar problem? I use Vuetify, but Vuetify uses icons from cdn.jsdelivr.net, so  in my application disappears all icons.

Try to access scripts placed on cdn.jsdelivr.net, specifically materialdesignicons.min.css

Me too. Access from Indonesia at 2024-05-02 04:05 (UTC Time)

me to at 2024-05-02 05:00:25 UTC

me too from Romania

same problem in germany 2024-05-02 06:43 UTC

me too, from Germany on 2024-05-02 08:45

Same problem in Hong Kong 2024-05-02 07:05 UTC. I don't think it's location specific.

Update: tested at 2024-05-02 13:27 UTC time. Problem already solved

@KoalaYeung it affect in some country. This is explanation from founder jsdelivr. https://www.jsdelivr.com/blog/jsdelivr-may-outage-postmortem/

Use alternative: gcore.jsdelivr.net or fastly.jsdelivr.net

works from germany as  a alternative. Thank you.

are you guys switching from cdn -> gcore ? I mean is this a temporary thing or what ?

@AlperBatıoğlu temporary solution before it up again. Or you can download all library you need and then use it

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/MaterialDesign-Webfont/7.4.47/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">

use alternative

I have the same issue and can fix it by migrating all libraries from jsdelivr.com to https://cdnjs.com. In my case, I can access the assets from jsdelivr.com by VPN, but I cannot without VPN.
